# Listing a very large number of files in a directory from Box drive in C#

Tags: c#, .net

I'm trying to get a list of files in a specific directory that contains over 20 million files ranging (2.5T).The problem is that my program throws the Out Of Exception everytime.

`

```
var archivos = Directory.EnumerateFiles(directoriosEntrada[i], "*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories);
```

Comment: Is there a specific reason why you don't use the Box API? https://developer.box.com/reference/resources/files/

Answer (score -1):

It may be because the C# debugger has a limit on how much it can store before crashing out (it happened the same to me when I a GUI with over 2500 objects in it).

Try using the same code without the debugger and it should not crash.

If it keeps crashing then it's because you're trying to use more RAM than what your computer has or more than VSCode can handle with debugger

Comment: i will try, but the problem Out Of Exception everytime when are doing Foreach

Comment: still the same error